# onCreate is duplicating views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm loosely following the sunshine course and I'm running into a problem.

In my `MainActivity onCreate` method, it originally called

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mStudentId = Utility.getStudentId(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

According to the tutorial, they say to add the following lines

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new TimeTableFragment(), TIMETABLEFRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
    }
```

As a result, there are now two list views overlayed on top of each other as duplicates, and I see the following:

[image]

What's causing this?

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.mcgowan.timetable.itsligotimetables.TimeTableFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

activity_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />


<include layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />

<!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
<!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
<!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"-->
<!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
<!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TimeTableFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_timetable" />
```

Comment: Do you have a `<fragment>` element in your layout for `TimeTableFragment`?

Comment: Post `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Post the xml's please...

Comment: You're ending up with two `TimeTableFragment`s; the one declared in the layout, and the one loaded dynamically. If you just want one, get rid of one of them.

Comment: If you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ending up with two `TimeTableFragment`s, as you've one declared in the layout, and you're loading one dynamically at runtime. Since you're following a course, it would seem that they're starting to teach you about dynamic `Fragment` handling and `FragmentTransaction`s, so you probably want to remove the `<fragment>` element from the layout.

However, your `FragmentTransaction` is specifying the `ViewGroup` with ID `container` as the container `View` for your `Fragment`. Currently, you have that ID set on the `CoordinatorLayout`, which is probably not really what you want. Instead, replace the `<fragment>` element with a `<FrameLayout>`, with the same `layout_width` and `layout_height`, and move the `android:id="@+id/container"` attribute to that.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments should be restored after a device rotation by default.

EDIT: sample code removed

And of course you need to save your data in the savedInstanceState bundle

Comment: This will most likely throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, since the layout isn't being set before loading the `Fragment`.

Comment: this. Throws a `RuntimeException`